# C# ASP.NET Inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, inheritance

How can i inherit the class, when i try to inherits it gives me an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class expresion2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public String nombre, email, telefono, contra, usuario;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nombre = txtNombre.Text;
        email = txtEmail.Text;
        telefono = txtTel.Text;
        contra = txtContra.Text;
        usuario = txtUser.Text;


    }
}
```

When i try inherit "expresion2" it gives me a compilation error on VS studio 2016

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class mostrar2 : expresion2
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your mostrar2 and expression2 classes are not defined in a namespace.

The correct definitions would be the below;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public partial class expresion2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public String nombre, email, telefono, contra, usuario;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nombre = txtNombre.Text;
            email = txtEmail.Text;
            telefono = txtTel.Text;
            contra = txtContra.Text;
            usuario = txtUser.Text;


        }
    }
}
```

And;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public partial class mostrar2 : expresion2
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work! still giving the same error, is there another way to inherit variables from expresion2 to mostra2?